# Get Drupal user into WordPress

Tags: wordpress, drupal, content-management-system

I have a Drupal site, and into it, a WordPress site.

I would like to know how to get user info of drupal site in WordPress site ?

in fact if your a user of wwww.mydrupalsite.com, how can I pass user info to www.mydrupalinfo.com/wordpress. ?

Thank for answer !

Answer (score 0):

You need to fill the wordpress table users (**wp_users** if you´re using the standard wordpress prefix) with the data of the "**users**" table of your Drupal database. Just make sure you **don't delete** the admin users of your wordpress site.
You can try this WordPress plugin though: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/external-database-authentication/ which can help you use an external database (drupal DB) for authentication on WordPress